# Formatting a Textbox (Phone Numbers, Mobile Numbers, Emails)

Tags: c#, textbox, format, string-formatting

I'd like to know how to cast textbox input into different formats. I tried using Format.String() since it's the 'solution' I found online after doing some research but it did not end well for me.

```
  private void RegHomePhoneTBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = RegHomePhoneTBox.Text;
        double sAsD = double.Parse(s);
        RegHomePhoneTBox.Text = string.Format("{0:###-####}", sAsD).ToString();
    }
```

This was the code block I used and it just keep on throwing an error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll Additional information: Input string was not in a correct
>   format.

Comment: What would be your sAsD value? something like this 2222222

Comment: I was thinking of using sAsD to take my TextBox's text. Like 3443434 then format it as 344-3434.

Comment: Instead of TextChanged Event, try your code in Leave Event, Or try Using MaskedTextBox Control

Comment: I'll check for the event. The reason I'm doing this is because I'm avoiding the MaskedTextBox.

Comment: The leave event works for me but it's not the way I wanted it to work out. I want to format it during the typing process not afterwards.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use a `MaskedTextBox`. It works just like a regular text box but the user is forced to enter text in a specific format.

In your specific case, just set the `Mask` property to `"000-0000"`.

Here's the documentation:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask(v=vs.110).aspx

There are lots of other properties in `MaskedTextBox` which are very useful, like `MaskCompleted`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  private void RegHomePhoneTBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s = RegHomePhoneTBox.Text;
        if (s.Length == 7)
        {
           double sAsD = double.Parse(s);
           RegHomePhoneTBox.Text = string.Format("{0:###-####}", sAsD).ToString();
        }
        if (RegHomePhoneTBox.Text.Length > 1)
             RegHomePhoneTBox.SelectionStart = RegHomePhoneTBox.Text.Length;
        RegHomePhoneTBox.SelectionLength = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Check it again.

Comment: I'll try once more sir. Thank you for the patience.

Comment: Just Try to type "111111111111" and see what happened

Comment: Tried it, thanks for the help. I might stick with this for a bit while looking for a desired solution. :D

Comment: Why you should tell it is not working? give me an example of input you type and the result you want.

Comment: I will fix it for you tonight

Comment: OK Explain The way you want